# Flask: cant connect to REDIS on vserver

Tags: javascript, html, flask, redis, server-sent-events

Currently im trying to make my website a little bit smarter. I installed on my vserver (hosted on Google cloud, ubuntu 20.10):

- everything to run my flask application
- nginx
- redis

the problem is, that i cant connect to the redis database by flask. Im trying to run this script:
https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

and it just doesnt work! if i connect over ssh to vserver and run:
`redis-cli` it responses "127.0.0.1:6379>". Ping works.

this is the startscript of gunicorn: `ExecStart=/home/foo/boo/mainenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --worker-class gevent --bind unix:mainsite.sock -m 007 wsgi:app server --log-level debug>`

this is the code in flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for, make_response, send_from_directory, Response, stream_with_context
from flask_sse import sse

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["REDIS_URL"] = "redis://localhost"
app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/stream')

@app.route('/hello')
def publish_hello():
    sse.publish({"message": "Hello!"}, type='greeting')
    return "Message sent!"

@app.route('/')
def Home():
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

this is the javascript

```
    var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('sse.stream') }}");
    source.addEventListener('greeting', function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        alert("The server says " + data.message);
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
        alert("Failed to connect to event stream. Is Redis running?");
    }, false);
```

it would be nice if you can help me... im trying to solve this problem for 2 days now...

Comment: Where is the redis port?

Comment: it doesnt work with the port too...

Comment: hey gabriel, could you try this as your redis config: `app.config["REDIS_URL"] = 'redis://'`

Comment: thanks shiny, i gave up and started using ws